# Add row and sum row based on two column values

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

The image shows what I am trying to achieve

[image]

The following are the conditions that I am trying to achieve

1. Sort Column F and H, then add a row when there is a value change in both rows. The condition must add a row when the values change

- Sell - D
- Sell - S
- Buy - D
- Buy - S

2. After creating the blank row the Column I must sum the values by looping and the summed value must populate in the newly inserted row
3. Copy the summed value to another worksheet into a particular cell, the code must work with any number of data.

The code I have for creating blank row works when the column is F and G but not working if there is a column in between:

```
Sub InsertRowsAtValueChange()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = WorkRng.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
    If WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).Value <> WorkRng.Cells(i - 1, 1),.Value 
    Or WorkRng.Cells(i, 2).Value <> WorkRng.Cells(i - 1, 2).Value Then
       
        WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
```

For summing

```
Range("I19:I22").Select
Range("I22").Activate
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[4]C:R[-1]C)"
```

But this works for the 4 rows if the data changes the sum function fails.

Comment: @braX I have added the code that I have used so far.

Comment: The first thing I would do is remove `On Error Resume Next` - that line will hide any problems you have and that will in turn cause more problems. Once removed, what error do you get that you were previously ignoring?

Comment: @braX There is no error when running the code